# How to access a bean in ServletContextListener's contextDestroyed

Tags: jsf, servlets, jpa, seam, jsf-1.2

I have a JSF application that uses JSF 1.2 and Servlets 2.3 and Seam 2.2.0. I want to run a sort of backup everytime the application closes. I have tried using the ServletContextListener like this:

```
public class ApplicationStartupAction implements ServletContextListener {
@In
FormActionImpl formAction;

public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println("Context destroyed");
    formAction.migrateForms();
}

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    //Do nothing
    System.out.println("Startup");
    }

}
```

I wanted to use the FormActionImpl class because that has access to the JPA-handlers and the database, and I need to access the database. This doesn't work (I get a nullpointerexception) for the line "forAction.migrateForms();". My best guess is that I can't use the injections, because those classes have already been destroyed at this stage of the shutdown?

Is there a way to gain access to managed beans during the shutdown? Or use JPA in some other way?

Comment: The `@In` is not recognizable as part of standard Java EE and therefore this question is hard to understand and answer. What is it? Are you using Seam? Is that really supposed to work in an instance which is apparently not managed by Seam like a servlet context listener? What exactly is `FormActionImpl`? If it were an application scoped JSF managed bean, then it'd be quite simple using the standard ways.

Comment: By the way, JSF 1.2 requires officially Servlet 2.5, but can run on Servlet 2.4 when using Facelets instead of JSP. So it surprises me that you managed to get it to work on Servlet 2.3 (evaluating EL expressions in JSF pages would in that case not work at all). Aren't you mixing versions?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I am using Seam, so @In is supposed to inject a context variable. In this case, the FormActionImpl is a statefull bean in a conversation scope. 

As far as I can tell, the application is using servlet-api-2.3.jar, and it is using EL expressions.

Comment: Why exactly did you expect a conversation scoped bean to be available during application shutdown? If it were an application scoped bean, I'd understand it as there can be only one. But a conversation scoped bean? There can be many ones during application's lifetime, how would the container know which one to inject? Are you sure you're looking for the solution in the right direction? Perhaps you'd better store the to-be-cleaned stuff in application scope (either manually or in flavor of an application scoped bean)